# How to get values from Extjs getUpdatedRecords()?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

When I try to retrieve just `grid.getStore().getUpdatedRecords()`, it works just fine, but when trying to enter that object and retrieve data from(data), I get *is undefined*

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        listeners: {
            'edit': function () {

                    var grid = Ext.getCmp('dataGrid');
                    var editedRecords = grid.getStore().getUpdatedRecords(); // <---- OK
                  //var editedFirstName = editedRecords.data.FirstName;
                  //console.log(editedFirstName);
                    console.log(editedRecords);
                }

         }
    })
]
```

Here is my Firebug showing that this object has *data.FirstName, data.LastName, data.id*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getUpdatedRecords returns an array of modified records. So you're code should be ...

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('dataGrid');
var editedRecords = grid.getStore().getUpdatedRecords(); // <---- OK
var editedFirstName = editedRecords[0].data.FirstName;
```

Considering that you are commiting the updated record after each edit, otherwise the method will return also other previous modified records.

Also there is an easier way to do this, and also more practical. The row editing event click takes two parameters the editor and the object e which contains:

```
grid - The grid this editor is on
view - The grid view
store - The grid store
record - The record being edited
row - The grid table row
column - The grid Column defining the column that initiated the edit
rowIdx - The row index that is being edited
colIdx - The column index that initiated the edit
```

So you're code should be

```
'edit': function (editor,e) {
     var grid = e.grid;
     var record = e.record;
     console.log(record.data.FirstName);
}
```